# Scroll to anchor in Prestashop (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, prestashop, anchor-scroll

please can you help me with small function - Im not skilled in JS / Jquery. I need scroll to anchor in Prestashop, all codes are function only in index.php, not at another pages (product page, category page ..)..

So I need rule for this function be active only on index.php page ..but code bellow is not function:(

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    var string = "index.php";
    if(url.indexOf(string) !== -1) {  
       $("a.linkscroll").live('click',function(event){
          event.preventDefault();
          var target_offset = $(this.hash).offset() ? $(this.hash).offset().top : 0;       
          var customoffset = 120;
          $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:target_offset - customoffset}, 2000);
        });
    }   
    else {
       echo "nothing there?"
    }
    }(jQuery));
```

Please, can you help me? (in menu a links I have class a.linkscroll = a href="index.php#some-anchor", so I can use this = another anchors I dont need to be use) ..scroll function I have used only in main page (index.php), anchors have ID (for example a id="some-anchor").

Thank you for your help!

Comment: UPG: Code up is now working correctly in my index.php, but from another pages is not possible "click" to link in menu again (link with class a.linkscroll).. If I delete this class "linkscroll" from a link (by deleting it in viewer source code), link is normaly function again (bring me back to index and to anchor position but not with smootscroll.

Answer (score 0):

Helllo [Jiri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6433461/jiri-drozen)

In Prestashop, you can find page name and its associate controller in `<body>` id.

You can pass the `$pagename` from your controller file, by assigning it to smarty variable.

The code to get a pagename is below:

```
$pagename = Dispatcher::getInstance()->getController();
```

You can override your `classes/controller/FrontController.php` file and inside it find `setMedia` function.

There you can write your code to add JS for only home page.

```
$pagename = Dispatcher::getInstance()->getController();
if ($pagename  == 'index') {
$this->addJS(_THEME_JS_DIR_.'custom.js');
}
```

Add your JS in your theme JS folder and you will see your JS only in homepage.

If you can not find your JS loaded then remove `cache/class_index.php` file.

After it will be display.

Comment: Hello vijay rami, thank you for your help! Yes, I will do this but i taught, that I have only some problem in my code up, because only menu links with "linkscroll" class are not function (is not possible clik on it) on other pages:(

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way without any override is to target the index.php page from the tpl files.

You can add it in any file, for example on the footer.

So I'll start targeting the index.php page and it's as easy as.

```
{if $page_name =='index'}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("a.linkscroll").on('click',function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                var customoffset = 120;
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top - customoffset,
                }, 2000);
            });
        });
    </scrpt>
{/if}
```

You can see a live example here: [JS Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/mzqgctm2/)

With that your code should work and only in the home page.